# Issue with carousel not calculating amount of "pages" right

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm trying to build a carousel using bxslider framework, however i cannot get the paging to work correctly.

For some reason it is not calculating the pages right:

[image]

It is saying that there is only 1 page, however there is 3 total slides and it is displaying two slides at once, hence, it should display 2 of 2 instead of 2 of 1.

Anyone got a solution for this?

This is my settings:

```
var slider = $slider.bxSlider({
   slideWidth: 350,
   minSlides: 1,
   maxSlides: 3,
   shrinkItems: true,
   nextText: "",
   prevText: "",
   pager: true,
   pagerType: "short",
   pagerShortSeparator: " of ",
   slideMargin: 60,
   responsive: true,
   auto: false,
   infiniteLoop: false,
   hideControlOnEnd: true,
});
```

Thank you

**Update**

I may have found a bug in the framework myself.
When you are using the paging type "short", in the bxslider source code line 823, the code is like this:

```
len = Math.ceil(slider.children.length / slider.settings.maxSlides);
```

However, there is a method that retrieves the amount of visible slides in the slider viewport, which is more correct to use:

```
len = Math.ceil(slider.children.length / getNumberSlidesShowing());
```

This way, the slider will now work responsively, since the number of visible slides is going to vary depending on your screen size.